# 2 expressões regulares em 1

Tags: javascript, regex

Encontrei a seguinte expressão regular para validar endereço de email em javascript:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Que funciona muito bem.
Gostaria de adicionar, nesta mesma expressão, as limitações mínimas e máximas de caracteres:

```
/^.{3,100}$/
```

Uma solução menos elegante é fazer 2 verificações (que é o que estou fazendo hoje).
É possível deixar tudo em uma única expressão?

Comment: Não sei se você percebeu, mas a sua regex já mensura o tamanho de específicos fragmentos da sua expressão. Pode ver, aliás, que existem vários `{1,3}` aí no meio que fazem toda a diferença. Você pode saber mais testando a suas expressões e regras usando um debugger on-line, como o [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: É preciso ter muito cuidado com a validação de email, a meu ver convém deixar o mais simples possível, uma vez que há uma variedade enorme de possíveis emails. Eu faço uma validação bem simples para ver se tem: `texto@texto.texto`, só isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Embora eu concorde em princípio que deixar simples é bom, é preciso ter cuidado para não ter falsos negativos. Por exemplo, eu já andei usando a fórmula `meuemail+site@provedor.com` para evitar spam (e pra saber qual site em que me registrei vendeu meu e-mail pra spammers), mas muitos sites rejeitavam por causa do `+` no endereço - que é algo perfeitamente válido.

Comment: @mgibsonbr quando eu digo `texto@` queria dizer qualquer carácter válido.

Comment: Conselho: Use o [JQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) para a validação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Seriam "falsos positivos"? Haha.

Comment: Não recomendaria isso. A menos que voc~e tenha pensado em TODOS os possíveis excessos de burrice dos usuários e se protegida contra TODAS as possibilidades dessa ER falhar (o que é extremamente difícil na maioria dos cenários), cedo ou tarde essa ER vai precisar de manutenção, sej apor você ou outra pessoa. E venhamos e convenhamos que ler uma ER complexa não é assim tão fácil.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Se a lógica do OP depender de grupos de captura dentro dessa regex, então concordo com seu argumento. Caso contrário, não seria simplesmente o caso de substituir essa regex por outra caso ela precise de manutenção? Validar e-mails é uma tarefa comum, e existem iniciativas para se encontrar boas regexes que sejam de fato compatíveis com a especificação ([exemplo](https://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php)). É uma tarefa complexa, e soluções ad-hoc têm grande chance de conter erros IMHO.

Comment: Pois é, mas uma ER muito grande dificulta até mesmo reescrever uma nova revisão da mesma pois invariavelmente o programador terá que lê-la e interpretá-la. Não sei se JS tem suporte a ER *multiline* como o PHP em que você pode ir comentando cada segmento dela.

Comment: Misericórdia, que catástrofe ficou a redação do meu penúltimo comentário.

Comment: A resposta está correta mas eu concordo com os comentários e benefícios de uma validação simples já que se trata de um padrão que eu não tenho total controle e pode mudar independente de minhas regras de negócio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível usando [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=regex1)regex2
(?!regex1)regex2
```

No primeiro caso (*positive lookahead*), a engine verifica se a string casa com a `regex1`, mas sem consumí-la de fato, e depois procede para o casamento normal com a `regex2`. No segundo (*negative lookahead*) é a mesma coisa, mas a engine verifica se a string **não** casa com `regex1`.

Adaptando a seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
(?=^.{3,100}$)^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQAt3/1/) (usei 15 a 20 caracteres pra simplificar o teste). Fonte: [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13923652/520779).