# Como trabalhar com REGEx na validação de nomes?

Tags: regex

tentei de várias formas desenvolver uma Expressão Regular que faça a validação de:

1. tamanho máximo de 60 caracteres
2. não pode ser numero
3. não pode ter acentos, cedilha e pontuação
4. a primeira letra do nome
   maiúscula e o restante minuscula.

Exemplos de nomes verdadeiros:

- Jose da Silva
- Nycolas Merino
- Antonio Ferreira Pacheco

Exemplos de nomes falsos:

- Jose da silva
- Nycolas merino
- antonio Ferreira pacheco

O que eu consegui criar, é isso: `[A-Z][a-z]+[[ ][A-Z][a-z]+]*`
Porém, ela está validando apenas o primeiro e o segundo nome, se pessoa tiver 3 nomes não faz a validação de primeiro caracter "maisculo" e também não faz a validação de 60 caracteres. Sim, eu preciso fazer isso em expressão regular! Caso queira testar a expressão, pode fazer nesse site: http://ferramentas.lymas.com.br/regexp/regexp_br.php#

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: GMSantos .. C# / VB / .NET!
Segue uma expressão que já funciona para outra finalidade.

^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$

Essa expressão é colocada dentro de um XML para validação da resposta em uma questão.

Comment: Você não pode executar qualquer operação na String resultante? Uma simples linha poderia tanto limitar o número de caracteres como remover múltiplos espaços.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sua ideia geral está ok (casar o primeiro nome, e zero ou mais vezes casar um espaço seguido de outro nome), o problema está no uso de colchetes (`[]`) na segunda parte da expressão - colchetes casam um e somente um caractere, dentre as opções possíveis. Trocando por parênteses deve resolver o problema:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+([ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*
```

Note que, dependendo da forma como essa expressão é usada, ela pode casar somente *parte de* uma string (ex.: `123Fulano Beltrano456` teria seu "meio" casado). Se você quer garantir que a expressão somente case a string inteira, um meio é usando os delimitadores de início (`^`) e fim (`$`):

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+([ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

Por fim, se você tiver problema com grupos de captura, marque a expressão dentro dos parênteses como de "não captura":

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

Quanto a validar por um tamanho específico, [essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26158/215) numa pergunta relacionada (["2 expressões regulares em 1"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26144/215)) mostra um meio de se fazer isso usando *lookarounds* (i.e. teste a string pela primeira regex, sem consumi-la, então teste-a novamente pela segunda regex):

```
(?=^.{2,60}$)^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

[Exemplo no Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HUWqe6q3gx). P.S. Se você está usando essa regex dentro de um XML, então talvez os *lookaheads* [não estejam disponíveis](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). Acho que não é o caso, mas verifique se a *engine* utilizada dá suporte a essa funcionalidade. Caso contrário, há pouco que eu possa sugerir para você validar o tamanho, o ideal seria fazer isso em uma etapa separada (como [sugerido por Guill nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39161/como-trabalhar-com-regex-na-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-nomes/39179#comment76604_39161)).

Note que alguns dos seus nomes "válidos" são inválidos por essa regex - aqueles que possuem "da" no meio (iniciado em minúsculas). Se quiser fazer uma exceção para "da" (e talvez também para "do", "de" e "e") pode fazer algo como:

```
(?=^.{2,60}$)^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ](?:das?|dos?|de|e|[A-Z][a-z]+))*$
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://rubular.com/r/LDvhqMKgWQ).

Comment: mgibsonbr, obrigado pela ajuda!
Concerteza me atendeu, fiz algumas modificação acrescentando alguns caracteres com acentuação que agora são liberados!

Comment: mgibsonbr, porque temos isso no começo:

(?=^.{2,60}$)^

Quer dizer o que? E porque temos 2 começo de linha?

Comment: @NycolasMerino Pra não repetir a explicação aqui, veja a [pergunta linkada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26144/215). Resumidamente, estou juntando duas expressões regulares em uma, já que não dá pra "misturar" as duas (i.e. o tamanho e o conteúdo são validados separadamente). E é por isso também que temos dois começos (e dois finais) de linha - porque cada regex age independentemente. A propósito, `.{2,60}` significa "qualquer caractere, 2 a 60 vezes".

Answer (score 1):

Para nomes em português, aproveitando o que foi dito por @mgibsonbr, e juntando com mais algumas coisas que encontrei na net, consegui chegar a uma ReGex quase perfeita para nomes em português:

```
/(?=^.{2,60}$)^[A-ZÀÁÂĖÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚÛÇ][a-zàáâãèéêìíóôõùúç]+(?:[ ](?:das?|dos?|de|e|[A-Z][a-z]+))*$/
```