# Expressão Regular para encontrar exceção de palavra

Tags: regex

Estou em busca de uma determinada função recursiva a qual não me lembro o nome.
Para isto montei a seguinte ER:

```
function (\w+)\([\x00-\xFF]+\1\(
```

Que necessariamente ira buscar por todas as funções que chamem o próprio nome (recursivo).
Estou ciente de que o trecho `[\x00-\xFF]+` pode me trazer resultados inesperados como:

```
function rl(){
    // code
}

function teste(){
    rl();
}
```

Contudo, isto é irrelevante.

Meu problema se consiste em negar determinados nomes como `index`, `busca`, `edit`,
para assim minimizar meus resultados.

Atualmente minha busca encontra 900 resultados, em que, creio eu, uns 70% deles são referente a estas funções.

Tentativas falhas:

```
function ([^(index|busca|edit)])\(.*\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\1\(
function ((?<!index)\w+)\(.*\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\1\(
```

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer não dá para fazer apenas com expressões regulares tradicionais como elas são definidas. Entretanto o javascript usa expressões regulares estendidas com lookahead, lookbehind e backreferences podendo pegar algumas coisas que não são de fato linguagens regulares. Vou dar uma olhada nisso para ver se consigo te ajudar, o caminho parece ser backreferences.

Comment: Se percebi bem tens esta pergunta que te pode ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26144/2-express%C3%B5es-regulares-em-1

Comment: jsantos1991. Obrigado a referencia. foi com ela que achei a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda da referencia prestada pelo jsantos1991.
E do site de testes http://regex101.com/

Utilizando ER sobre ER. Cheguei ao resultado:

```
(?!function (index|edit|busca))(function (\w+)\(.*\)[\x00-\xFF]+\3\()
```

Na primeira parte:

```
(?!function (index|edit|busca))
```

É realizada uma busca por tudo que não seja "function index" ou "function edit" ou "function busca".
Na qual ja temos nosso primeiro grupo: `(index|edit|busca) nosso \1`

O segundo grupo é a própria ER: `(function (\w+)\(.*\)[\x00-\xFF]+\3\() nosso \2`

Na segunda ER:

```
(function (\w+)\(.*\)[\x00-\xFF]+\3\()
```

temos o terceiro grupo: `(\w+) nosso \3`

Nela se é buscado, como dito na pergunta, funções que fazem referencias a elas mesmas.

Em conclusão a segunda ER busca pelas funções e a primeira diz quais não capturar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui com uma função javascript meio complicada:

```js
function localizaRecursoes(codigo) {
    var regex = new RegExp("function[\\s]+([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[\\s]*\\(.*\\)[\\s]*\{[\x01-\xFF]*\\1\\(", "g");
    var resultado = [];
    var match = null;
    do {
        match = regex.exec(codigo);
        if (match != null && match[1].indexOf("index") == -1 && match[1].indexOf("busca") == -1 && match[1].indexOf("edit") == -1) {
            resultado.push(match[1]);
        }
    } while (match != null);
    return resultado;
}
```

Para testar ela:

```js
localizaRecursoes("function foo() { foo(); } function xoom() { xoom(); } function foq() { hghf(); } function ga() { ga(); } function buscaX() { buscaX(); } function yy() { yy(); } function feq() { hghf(); } function fre() { ghghgh fre(); dfsfdsf }");
```

Resultado:

```js
["foo", "xoom", "ga", "yy", "fre"]
```

Comment: Victor. agradeço a tentativa, mas infelizmente utilizando este método eu teria de forcar que uma variável lese os arquivos no ERP inteiro. passando no codigo.

Minha ideia é mais simples apenas usando o ctrl+h (busca geral)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, você não escolheu uma linguagem específica então estarei fazendo com PHP por ter maior familiaridade mas a ER em si eu acredito ser funcional em outras linguagens contanto que estas suportem *lookaround assertions* e, se necessário, recebam os devidos ajustes específicos da linguagem:

```
/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/
```

É casada uma palavra (`\w+`) que não seja uma das proibidas (`(?!(palavra|palavra|palavra))`).

Depois são casados os parênteses com qualquer coisa dentro para uma possível lista de argumentos. Pode remover caso não precise deles.

Em seguida são casadas as chaves delimitadoras de um bloco de código e, dentro delas qualquer caractere (`[\x00-\xFF]+`), seguido da nossa função anteriormente casada (`\\1`), os parênteses e seu conteúdo (também passíveis de remoção) e qualquer coisa de novo, assim a função pode aparecer em qualquer parte do bloco de código.

Os testes:

```
$str1 = 'function rl($a){
    rl($a)
}';

$str2 = 'function rl($a){
    //code
}';

$str3 = 'function index($a){
    anotherfunction($a)
}';

$str4 = 'function edit($a){
    edit($a)
}';

$str5 = 'function rl(){
    edit();
}';

preg_match( '/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/', $str1, $m1 );
preg_match( '/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/', $str2, $m2 );
preg_match( '/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/', $str3, $m3 );
preg_match( '/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/', $str4, $m4 );
preg_match( '/function ((?!edit|busca|edit)\w+)\((.*?)\)\{[\x00-\xFF]+\\1\(\\2\)[\x00-\xFF]+\}/', $str5, $m5 );

var_dump( $m1, $m2, $m3, $m4, $m5 );
```

Apenas o primeiro casa alguma coisa, pois:

- No segundo a função não se chama recursivamente
- No terceiro temos um nome proibido
- No quarto temos um nome proibido e uma recursividade de um nome proibido
- No quinto temos um nome válido, mas sem ter a função chamada recursivamente